# protractor : Is it possible to read value from file in conf.js

Tags: protractor

I want team to specify `implicitwait` timeouts in a file, whether a `property file, .ini or xml`.

Is there any way by which I can configure `implicitwait` timeout value from file, rad it from there and configure the driver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can user params object inside your conf.js to use any global variables that can be used inside any of your tests.Look at the below sample conf.js,

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  params:{
     implicitWaitTime:5000
   }
}
```

Now you can use the value for implicitWaitTime variable inside any of your test by `browser.params.implicitWaitTime`